# PhpStorm shows Missing return statement when switch default to throw exception

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm marks this method with "Missing return statement" warning.

And I am wondering if how to get rid of this, because of warnings when creating commit, etc. But without to turn off the inspection.

[image: Missing return statement warning]

I know I could throw exception on end of method, and PhpStorm would be satisfied.

```
public static function getSomething(string $var)
{
    switch ($var)
    {
        case 1: return something();
        case 2: return somethingElse();
        default: throw new NowSomethingCompletelyDifferentException();
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with code I am missing?

Or should I address this to JetBrains?

Comment: *"I know I could throw exception on end of method"* Considering the provided code sample -- that would be the most readable solution. **In any case:** I see no warning in your code in PhpStorm 2017.2.4 running on Windows 10. Maybe you should provide a better example (e.g. whole file/bunch of files) and try it first in brand new project.

Answer (score 1):

Check the PHPStorm documentation [Disabling and Enabling Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html) or [Suppressing Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/suppressing-inspections.html):

> **Disabling and Enabling Inspections**
>
> To disable an inspection for highlighted issue in the editor
>
> When you disable inspections this way, they are disabled for the
> current inspection profile. To re-enable inspections disabled this
> way, use the main procedure described above.
>
> Set the caret at a highlighted issue.
>
> 1. Click the bulb icon or press Alt+Enter to reveal the inspection
>    alert and suggestion list.
> 2. Select the inspection to be disabled, then click right arrow button
>    or just press the right arrow key.
> 3. On the submenu, click Disable .

Answer (score 1):

you could refactor if it's really bothering you

```
public static function getSomething(string $var)
{
  $foo = [1 => 'something', 2 => 'somethingElse'];

  $method = $foo[$var];
  if $foo == NULL {
    throw new NowSomethingCompletelyDifferentException();
  }

  call_user_func($method);
}
```

But I would not recommend changing code for sake of satisfying your IDE. Only if you think this code is better (it might be).

Or you can file a bug in jetbrains and wait for a fix.