# Try/catch statement with return on class method

Tags: php, phpstorm

So I have a method inside my class, that does a `GET` request and then there are error handlers and various other components, but then if the response is good, it will be returned inside `// THE 200 RESPONSE IS HERE`.

How would I be able to make the method return the try/catch `$response_body` outside the try/catch if it's successful? So I have can `return $response_body` at the end of the method so that I have a valid return.

Update:
[image]

**So I have the following method inside my class**:

```
public function get_posts_via_rest_api(): array
    {
        $page = 1;
        try {
            $response = wp_remote_get(
                $this->global_endpoint . '?page=' . $page
            );
            if ((!is_wp_error($response)) && (200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response))) {
                $response_body = json_decode(
                    $response['body'],
                    false,
                    512,
                    JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR
                );
                if (empty($response_body)) {
                    return [];
                }
                if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {

                    // THE 200 RESPONSE IS HERE

                    $posts = $response_body;
                }
            } else {
                error_log(
                    print_r(
                        'Error: ' . $response->get_error_message()
                    )
                );

                return [];
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log(
                print_r(
                    'Error: ' . $e,
                    true
                )
            );

            return [];
        }

        // THIS SHOWS ERROR IN IDE
        return $posts;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `$posts = $response_body;`, simply put `return $response_body;`. All other possible return paths are handled with empty arrays

Comment: @Phil, when I do that, I get an error that there is no return statement at the end of the method. So I simply `return []` at the end of the method?

Comment: What's the context for that error? Where does it come from? Where do you see it reported? Whatever is producing it isn't PHP and is failing in its duty to perform static code analysis

Comment: All PHPStorm is indicating is 'No return statement' at the end, I have the method data type set as `array` as this: `public function get_posts_via_rest_api(): array`. It is not a static function, it's a method inside a class.

Comment: [IDE's aren't always correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46363888/283366). This is a false positive

Comment: Thank you @Phil, I update the post with a photo, looks like it's highlighted in red, but it's not throwing any debug errors.

Comment: The code posted doesn’t match the screenshot

Comment: @ChrisHaas, how so? It's the bottom of the method with the advice that Phil provided, I removed the bottom `return $posts` statement and update the `return $response_body` to replace `$posts = $response_body;`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I just updated a new screenshot.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I thought that was the bottom, that’s from the first `else`, sorry

Comment: Inside your first `if` statement are two sub-conditions. If neither of those two are true, your first `if` won’t return.

Comment: @ChrisHaas but there's a `return` in the corresponding `else`. OP has covered all the bases. I'd be searching the PHPStorm issues list for a bug around this particular inspection

Comment: Thanks all, as long as the code checks out and I'm not getting any debug error, which it looks like works just fine now, I will put in a IDE bug request.

Comment: One way to make the IDE happy would be to remove all the `return [];` in your `else` and `catch` blocks and just put that once at the end. The function will still return `$response_body` if you've got that in the happy path

Comment: @Phil, I was always taught to return as early as possible, would this cause any additional strain if I return at the end?

Comment: Your corresponding `else` might not actually hit. Maybe the system guarantees it, but PHPStorm can’t be sure through just static analysis alone. Your code is basically a version of this: https://3v4l.org/flbP5. What you want is something like https://3v4l.org/1NUWT

Comment: It's no strain. If you've got a bunch of paths all returning the same thing, there's no issue in consolidating that

Comment: @ChrisHaas nicely explained. I missed that too. The issue with OP's code is that `if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE)` is totally redundant

Comment: @ChrisHaas, you might be 100% right and I don't think it'll ever hit, but since this is going on a corporate website, I wanted to cover all cases JUST INCASE it does ever reach it for whatever known reason, so I don't get a production error.

Comment: Would you two be able to update an answer with a better formatted method if you don't mind, so I can compare mine to yours and see if I'm overdoing things?

Comment: Yes, I’ll try to provide an answer. I honestly enjoy these back and forths in the comments where we work together to find an answer, and I very much appreciate you being online during this, which isn’t often the case!

Comment: I can't thank you two enough, this is how I learn the best and improve my skillset, so I appreciate both you and Phil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```php
> if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
> ```

PHPStorm doesn't know that this statement is redundant (you've already told `json_decode()` to throw exceptions) so all it sees is a potential logic path missing a return value because there's no `else` to this `if`.

You can simplify your code to use the following

```php
$response_body = json_decode(
    $response['body'],
    false,
    512,
    JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR
);

return empty($response_body) ? [] : $response_body;
```

Now all your paths are covered.

---

You could also consolidate all your *unhappy* path return values into one statement at the end of your method.

The above can become

```php
if (!empty($response_body)) {
    return $response_body;
}
```

and remove all the `return [];` and place a single return at the end.

Comment: This is a good answer, I missed the try with throw, followed by error check, good spotting!

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments, your code is missing an edge case that might not logically be possible but your static analysis cannot be absolutely certain of it. From its perspective, your code is effectively [this](https://3v4l.org/flbP5) however it needs to handle the edge case like [this](https://3v4l.org/1NUWT). (As I write this, Phil has responded, and I think his answer is more correct, but I’m going to post anyway.) In this answer, this first `if` block has a terminal `return` (with error logging)

```php
public function get_posts_via_rest_api(): array
    {
        $page = 1;
        try {
            $response = wp_remote_get(
                $this->global_endpoint . '?page=' . $page
            );
            if ((!is_wp_error($response)) && (200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response))) {
                $response_body = json_decode(
                    $response['body'],
                    false,
                    512,
                    JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR
                );
                if (empty($response_body)) {
                    return [];
                }
                if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {

                    // THE 200 RESPONSE IS HERE

                    $posts = $response_body;
                }

                error_log(
                    print_r(
                        'Error: An unexpected condition happened'
                    )
                );

                return [];
            } else {
                error_log(
                    print_r(
                        'Error: ' . $response->get_error_message()
                    )
                );

                return [];
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log(
                print_r(
                    'Error: ' . $e,
                    true
                )
            );

            return [];
        }

        // THIS SHOWS ERROR IN IDE
        return $posts;
    }
```

**EDIT**

But, here’s how I would actually write it (untested, but should show the gist). First, try small, second, break out of your `if` blocks whenever possible, and third, return early.

```php
public function get_posts_via_rest_api(): array
    {
        $page = 1;
        try {
            $response = wp_remote_get(
                $this->global_endpoint . '?page=' . $page
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log(
                print_r(
                    'Error: ' . $e,
                    true
                )
            );

            return [];
        }

        if (is_wp_error($response) || (200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response)) {

            error_log(
                print_r(
                    'Either an error happened or a non-200 did',
                    true
                )
            );

            return [];
        }

        try{
            $response_body = json_decode(
              $response['body'],
              false,
              512,
                   JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR
                );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log(
                print_r(
                    'JSON Error: ' . $e,
                    true
                )
            );

            return [];
        }

        return $response_body;
    }
```

Comment: Learning to “outdent” or “unnest” your code can make it more verbose, but it can also make it easier to read. I think of this style as the same as isolating code to functions, without actually creating functions.